# Import Multiple Images with Magmi

Tags: magmi, importexport

I'm trying to import multiple product images into Magento using magmi and also add products to different category trees in the same import.

I've tried using `;` to separate images under the `media_gallery` csv column heading and also to separate categories in the `categories`
 column heading.

I'm getting now errors when I run the import but only one image and category is being created.  the second image is being totllay missed and the ';' in the category is being added as a category as a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was I was renaming the images with `{item.name}-{item.sku}.jpg`, so both images were getting the same name and being overwritten.  I just removed the image renaming from the magmi config and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use double ; to separate the categories for example
Cat1;;Cat2

And for the media gallery I have found setting a blank label seems to help although this shouldn't be necessary so that the format here would be 
URL1::;URL2::

Hope this helps.